# build a quadrants with enumeration

Tags: java

I am learning about enumeration but I really have no idea how it works and how I can get started. Following is what I am working on.

```
// An enumeration which models the four quadrants of the 2D Cartesian
// plane.  It has exactly four elements: Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4.  It is likely
// that giving each some fields will make the implementation easier.
// A private constructor is also useful.
```

I first created some fields and a contructor:

```
private int x;
private int y;
private Quadrant (int x, int y)
{
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
}

public enum Quadrant { Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4;} //is this right?

// true if x-coordinates are positive in the quadrant, false otherwise

public boolean xPositive();

// true if y-coordinates are positive in the quadrant, false otherwise

public boolean yPositive();

// Return a String which represents the signs of the coordinates in
// the Quadrant as

//   (+,+) for Q1
//   (-,+) for Q2
//   (-,-) for Q3
//   (+,-) for Q4

public String signPair();
```

**for signPair, I really dont know what it means.
How can I make (+,+) related to Q1?**

```
// Return the Quadrant that would result from flipping the sign (pos
// to neg or neg to pos) of the x-coordinate in this Quadrant..

public Quadrant flipX();

// Given two integers, determine return the quadrant in which they
// reside. If either x or y is 0, return one of the valid quadrants
// it might be assigned to (this case is not tested).

public static Quadrant fromInts(int x, int y);

// Accept an arbitrary number of command line arguments. Adjacent
// pairs of arguments are treated as (x,y) coordinates.  Print the
// quadrant in which the pair resides along with the signPair(). If
// an odd number of arguments is given, ignore the last  
// argument. Any argument that cannot be converted to an integer
// should raise an exception on encountering it.

public static void main(String [] args)
```

- Attempt to convert each string argument to an integer. The function Integer.parseInt() is useful for such conversions. Any failure to convert to an integer should raise an exception. Integer.parseInt() exceptions on encountering problems so there is no need to explicitly throw anything.
- Treat adjacent arguments as pairs of integers. In processing the arguments, you will be looking at them two at a time.
- For each pair of integers, generate the Quadrant to which the pair belongs.
- Print out the pair of numbers and use the quadrant to print out the signs of the numbers and the quadrant they belong in. Use the following general format：

  **(1,5) has signs (+,+) and is in Q1**
- If the number of arguments is odd, ignore the last argument as it is an x-coordinate without a y-coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the amount of code by passing the fundamental properties as properties with each enum. `signPair` uses some elementary arithmetic properties to compute the ordinal of the flipped quadrant.

```
public enum Quadrant { 
  Q1(true,true),
  Q2(false, true),
  Q3(false, false),
  Q4(true, false);

  private boolean xpos;
  private boolean ypos;
  Quadrant( boolean xpos, boolean ypos ){
    this.xpos = xpos;
    this.ypos = ypos;
  }
  public boolean xPositive(){
    return xpos;
  }
  public boolean yPositive(){
    return ypos;
  }
  public String signPair(){
    return "(" + (xpos ? "+" : "-") + "," + (ypos ? "+" : "-") + ")";
  }
  public Quadrant flipX(){
    return values()[ordinal() + 1 - 2*(ordinal()%2)];
  }
  public static Quadrant fromInts(int x, int y){
    if( x >= 0 ){
      return y >= 0 ? Quadrant.Q1 : Quadrant.Q4;
    } else {
      return y >= 0 ? Quadrant.Q2 : Quadrant.Q3;
    }
  }
}
```

You can also define methods for each enum:

```
public enum Quadrant { 
  Q1(true,true){
    public Quadrant flipX(){ return Quadrant.Q2; }
    public String signPair(){ return "(+,+)"; }
  },
  Q2(false, true){
    public Quadrant flipX(){ return Quadrant.Q1; }
    public String signPair(){ return "(-,+)"; }
  },
  Q3(false, false){
    public Quadrant flipX(){ return Quadrant.Q4; }
    public String signPair(){ return "(-,-)"; }
  },
  Q4(true, false){
    public Quadrant flipX(){ return Quadrant.Q3; }
    public String signPair(){ return "(+,-)"; }
  };
  //...
  public abstract String signPair();
  public abstract Quadrant flipX();
  //...
}
```

Here's a test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  for( Quadrant q: Quadrant.values() ){
    System.out.println( q );
    System.out.println( q.xPositive() );
    System.out.println( q.yPositive() );
    System.out.println( q.signPair() );
    System.out.println( q.flipX() );
  }
  for( int x = -1; x <= 1; ++x ){
    for( int y = -1; y <= 1; ++y ){
      System.out.println( Quadrant.fromInts(x, y) );
    }
  }
}
```

To run the required main, process arguments:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   for( int i = 2; i <= args.length; i++ ){
      int x = Integer.parseInt( args[i-2] );
      int y = Integer.parseInt( args[i-1] );
      Quadrant q = Quadrant.fromInts(x, y);
      System.out.println("( + x + "," + y + ") in " + q + " " + q.signPair());
   }
 }
```

Comment: awesome! but thats really too much for me, I need to digest it slowly to get a full understanding. Besides, how about the main method? I have post some requirements about what main method should do.

Comment: I've added a test - but you might have done that, too.

Comment: @laune Although your answer is correct, I'd like to point out that the use of `ordinal()` is considered bad practice.

Comment: @Magnamag The alternative `Integer.parseInt(q.name().substring(1))-1` isn't preferable, especially when `Q1`,... `Q4` isn't likely to be changed, so that `ordinal()` will remain stable. - Anyway: use the alternative I've posted if you prefer.